# error signal(SIGABRT) raised in C program

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, sigabrt

Couldn't understand why my program is producing an error signal.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
int MAX_SIZE = 1;       
char stack[1];     
int top = -1;            

int isempty() {
   if(top == -1)return 1;
   else return 0;
}
   
int isfull() {
   if(top == 0)return 1;
   else return 0;
}

int pop() {
   int data;
    
   if(!isempty()) {
      data = stack[top];
      top = top - 1;   
      return data;
   } else {
      printf("Could not retrieve data, Stack is empty.\n");
   }
}

void push(int data) {

   if(!isfull()) {
      top = top + 1;   
      stack[top] = data;
   } else {
      printf("Could not insert data, Stack is full.\n");
   }
}

struct Node* newNode(int d){
    struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = d;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

struct Node* reverse(struct Node* head){
    //reverses the linked list and returns the pointer pointing to the first node of the reversed linked list.
    struct Node *prev = NULL, *curr = head;
 
    while (curr) {
        struct Node* temp = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = temp;
        free(temp);
    }
    head = prev;
    return head;
}

struct Node* addition(struct Node* first, struct Node* second){

    struct Node *rev1, *rev2;
    struct Node *res = NULL, *revres = NULL;
    struct Node *temp, *prev = NULL;
    int carry = 0, sum;

    rev1 = reverse(first);
    rev2 = reverse(second);
 
    while (rev1 != NULL || rev2 != NULL) {
        sum = carry + (rev1 ? rev1->data : 0) + (rev2 ? rev2->data : 0);
        carry = (sum >= 1000) ? 1 : 0;
        sum = sum % 1000;
        temp = newNode(sum);
        
        if (res == NULL)
            res = temp;
        else
            prev->next = temp;

        prev = temp;
        if (rev1)
            rev1 = rev1->next;
        if (rev2)
            rev2 = rev2->next;
    }
    if (carry > 0){
        struct Node *new = newNode(carry);
        temp->next = new;
        free(new);
    }
    revres = reverse(res);
    while (revres->data == 0 && revres->next) {
        struct Node* temp = revres;
        revres = revres->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return revres;
}

int length_reversal(struct Node** head_ref){

    // reverses the given linkedlist in-place and also returns the number of nodes in the list.
    struct Node* prev = NULL;
    struct Node* current = *head_ref;
    struct Node* next;
    int len = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        len++;
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    *head_ref = prev;
    return len;
}

void addData(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data){

    struct Node* new_node = newNode(new_data);
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
    free(new_node);
}


struct Node* make_empty_list(int size){

    struct Node* head = NULL;
    while (size--)
        addData(&head, 0);
    return head;
}

struct Node* multiplication(struct Node* first, struct Node* second){

    int m = length_reversal(&first), n = length_reversal(&second);
    struct Node* result = make_empty_list(m + n + 1);
    struct Node *second_ptr = second, *result_ptr1 = result, *result_ptr2, *first_ptr;
    while (second_ptr) {
 
        int carry = 0;
        result_ptr2 = result_ptr1;
 
        first_ptr = first;
 
        while (first_ptr) {
            int mul = first_ptr->data * second_ptr->data + carry;
            result_ptr2->data += mul % 1000;
            carry = (mul / 1000) + (result_ptr2->data / 1000);
            result_ptr2->data = result_ptr2->data % 1000;
 
            first_ptr = first_ptr->next;
            result_ptr2 = result_ptr2->next;
        }
        if (carry > 0) {
            result_ptr2->data += carry;
        }
 
        result_ptr1 = result_ptr1->next;
        second_ptr = second_ptr->next;
    }
    length_reversal(&result);
    length_reversal(&first);
    length_reversal(&second);
    while (result->data == 0 && result->next) {
        struct Node* temp = result;
        result = result->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return result;
}

struct Node* input(FILE* fp){
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    struct Node *result = NULL, *first= NULL;
    struct Node *it1 = NULL, *it2 = NULL, *it3 = NULL;
    char str[3];
    while(EOF != (ch=fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n'){
        if(ch == '=')return it1;
        else if(ch == '0'||ch == '1'||ch == '2'||ch == '3'||ch == '4'||ch == '5'||
                ch == '6'||ch == '7'||ch == '8'||ch == '9'){
                    if(i==3){printf("invalid input\n"); return NULL;}
                    str[i] = ch;
                    i++;
                }
        else if(ch == '+'){
            push(ch);
        }
        else if(ch == '*'){
            push(ch);
        }
        else if(ch == '$'){
            it3 = newNode(atoi(str));
            i = 0;
            if(!first){
                if(!it1)it1 = it3;
                else it2 = it3;
            }
            else{
                first->next = it3;
                first = NULL;
            }
            if(!isempty()){
                char c = pop();
                if(c == '+'){result = addition(it1, it2); it1 = result; it2 = NULL;}
                if(c == '*'){result = multiplication(it1, it2); it1 = result; it2 = NULL;}
            }
        }
        else if(ch == ','){
            if(first != NULL){
                it3 = newNode(atoi(str));
                first->next = it3;
                first = first->next;
                i=0;
            }
            else{
                if(!it1){
                    first = newNode(atoi(str));
                    it1 = first;
                    i=0;
                }
                else{
                    first = newNode(atoi(str));
                    it2 = first;
                    i=0;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(ch == ' ') continue;
        else {
            printf("Invalid input");
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return it1;
}

void output(FILE *fout, struct Node* list) {
    struct Node *temp;
    for (temp = list; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        fprintf (fout, "%03d,", temp->data);
    fprintf(fout, "%03d$", temp->data);
    fprintf (fout, "\n");
}

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input_txt.txt", "r");
    char c;
    while(EOF != (c=getc(fp)) && c != '='){
        ungetc(c, fp);
        struct Node* res = input(fp);
        if(res){
            output(stdout, res);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried using a debugger to understand the problem, but no luck there.

The problem was described as
"""You will represent an arbitrarily large unsigned integer I by a singly linked list of its DIGITs d1 ,
d2 , ... , dm , where d1 is the least significant DIGIT of I and dm is the most significant DIGIT of I.
Assume that the DIGITs are from a number system with base 1,00010. Implement each DIGIT as a C
unsigned int with DIGIT values in [0, 999].
a) Write C functions to perform the arithmetic operations addition and multiplication of large
unsigned integers.
b) Write a C function to input a large unsigned integer from stdin as comma separated DIGITs
in decimal, ordered on decreasing significance and terminated by a $
c) Write a C function to output a large unsigned integer to stdout in the format used for input,
showing each DIGIT as 3 decimal digits.
d) Write a C main() which will repeatedly accept (from stdin) and evaluate, large integer infix
expressions on large unsigned integer constants using the operators “+” (addition) and “*”
(multiplication). An expression is terminated by “=”. On encountering an “=”, the value of
the expression is to be printed to stdout. Evaluate expressions from left to right. The main() loop
should terminate when it receives an empty expression (terminated by =)."""

This was my assignment question for which the deadline was over a week ago and I couldn't figure out the problem with my code.

## For example, the 2 line input
111,041,411,111,011$ + 222,222$ * 003$ =

results in the output
333,124,233,999,699$

Comment: Did you try running your code with a debugger to find what line causes the crash? I did, and you are freeing the same memory more than once. I won't go through all the code to figure out exactly why though.

Comment: Took a quick look at the code and it seems like you have some major issues with memory handling. For example in the `addData()` function, you allocate a new node, save a pointer to it in head_ref, then you free the newly created node? The freshly stored pointer is then useless.

Comment: Yes, I did try using debugger and it pauses on exception, after making the edit you suggested, my code is running perfectly as expected. Thanks @Klas-Kenny

Comment: Why do you think that 'stack[top] = data' is an issue?? @Gerhard

Comment: I see there is checks { `isempty()` ,`isfull()` } so disregard my comment.